# Firebaseref.unauth() not loggin the user out

Tags: firebase-authentication

I sm uing firebase user email authentication in my app. 
and implementing the sign out option using below code, on selecting item 3 , the sign out should work

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id){
        case R.id.item1:
            break;
        case R.id.item2:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, task2_activity.class);
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            {
                ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,navigationView,"testAnim");
                this.startActivity(intent,options.toBundle());
            }
            else
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        **case R.id.item3:
            Firebase firebaseRef = new Firebase("https://apuroopah9.firebaseio.com/");
            firebaseRef.unauth();**

            break;
    }
```

But nothing happens upon clicking item3

Comment: "nothing happens" is not really clear. Does the code get executed? What did you expect it to do that it doesn't do at that stage?

Comment: I have a print statement         System.out.println("-------------------------->>>>> logout called");
followed by firebaseref.unath() call. This method call is supposed to log out the current session that is not happening

Comment: "This method call is supposed to log out the current session that is not happening." How are you seeing that the user is not logged out after this call?

Comment: I am on my front page activity when the app loads after successful login, then I click on logout option on the navigation drawer which is item 3, I still stay on the same page. Under item3 I am creating the firebase reference and calling unauth() on it.